# Create a class dynamicaly in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

Can I create a dynamic class at runetime, withot knowing the fields name of the class beforehand?

For example, if I let the user entre a list of strings, and when he sends the list, I create a class with the name of the fields as the list of strings.

For example, if I get:

```
List<string> TempList = new List<string>() { "Name1", "Name2" };
```

Can I create a class at runetime like this?

```
public class CustomClass(){
    public string Name1;
    public string Name2;
}
```

Comment: You're looking for a dictionary.

Comment: ExpandoObject is closer to what you're asking for, but probably isn't what you want.

Comment: The problem is how would you write the code to access the properties in the class? I think SLaks' idea about using Dictionary is a good one.

Comment: Yes you can create a class dynamically at runtime. Also it would be nice if you can let us know on how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class at runtime using Reflection.Emit if that is what you wish. One possible way is for you to do the following.

You use this class to execute the whole process. Close the type T with the appropriate type you wish for your properties. In your case, you would use type string.

```
class ClassFromList<T>
{
    public object Instance { get; set; }

    public ClassFromList(List<string> list)
    {
        var type = new DynamicClass().Builder;

        list.ForEach(item => new DynamicProperty<T>(type, item));

        Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type.CreateType());
    }
}
```

Within the above mentioned class, this one will provide you with a property of type TypeBuilder, so you can create a class at runtime.

```
class DynamicClass
{
    public TypeBuilder Builder { get; set; }

    public DynamicClass()
    { 
        var name = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly");
        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("DynamicModule");

        Builder = module.DefineType("DynamicClass", TypeAttributes.Public);
    }
}
```

While on the other hand, the following class will create the properties you wish your class to implement for you.

```
class DynamicProperty<T>
{
    public DynamicProperty(TypeBuilder builder, string name)
    {
        var field = builder.DefineField("_" + name, typeof(T), FieldAttributes.Private);
        var property = builder.DefineProperty(name, PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(T), new Type[0]);
        var getter = builder.DefineMethod("get_" + name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName, typeof(T), new Type[0]);
        var setter = builder.DefineMethod("set_" + name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName, null, new Type[] { typeof(T) });

        var getGenerator = getter.GetILGenerator();
        var setGenerator = setter.GetILGenerator();

        getGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
        getGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        setGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        property.SetGetMethod(getter);
        property.SetSetMethod(setter);
    }
}
```

Now you simply need to test the whole process. The following code will create 3 properties named "a", "b", "c" of type string, add values "value1, "value2", "value3" to them respectively, create an instance of your new class, and display all the properties, their types and values to you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

        var instance = new ClassFromList<string>(list).Instance;

        instance.GetType().GetProperty("a").SetValue(instance, "value1", null);
        instance.GetType().GetProperty("b").SetValue(instance, "value2", null);
        instance.GetType().GetProperty("c").SetValue(instance, "value3", null);

        instance.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name + " " + x.PropertyType + " " + x.GetValue(instance, null)));

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you actually need fields in your class, as I have just noticed, you should use the DynamicField class instead of the DynamicProperty class which is the following. But note that properties are preferred over fields for data transfer between objects.

```
class DynamicField<T>
{
    public DynamicField(TypeBuilder builder, string name)
    {
        var field = builder.DefineField(name, typeof(T), FieldAttributes.Public);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the acurate answer, i will try this.

Comment: Glad I could help, and don't forget to check the answer as the correct one if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should use :

> DynamicObject Class

There's a link how to use it : [DynamicObject Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but that's probably not what he wants.